# EC2 Autoscaling group launching more instances than required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

I have setup an ecs cluster with ec2 autoscaling group as capacity provider. When I deploy one service to my cluster. It launches 2 ec2 tasks(or service as there is just one task in service). And then later on kill one of the instance by scaling down. If I launch 2 tasks then it scales to 4 instances and then after that scales down after some time. Now the most problematic thing here is that this stuff is happening continously and I am being charged continously. And if termination protection is off it's sometimes deleting instances which were in use and so they get deployed again which again triggers to launch 4 instances making this run even in an infinite loop. This would become pretty expensive for me if its not stopped at this point. I am clearly able to see that there are just 2 instances in use but still 2 more are there for no reason. Some information that might be needed -

1. Capacity provider target capacity is set to 100% and so I was expecting it to not scale extra and reserve more amount for future use ->

[image]

2. And that capacity provider is being used as default capacity provider strategy ->

[image]

3. My autoscaling group settings ->

[image]

Would be great if anyone can help me fix this.
Thanks

Comment: You posted the same image twice. Please show your auto-scaling group settings.

Comment: Hey @MarkB sorry for that. I have updated my question and added autoscaling group settings too.

Comment: @TusharVaswani did you try to increase Instance Warmup Period? 5 minutes works perfectly fine in my case.

Comment: @IlyaKhrustalev Just checked in my case default instance warmup is disabled.

Comment: Also @IlyaKhrustalev I just tried to enable it and make it 300 seconds but still its behaving the same.

Comment: Did you check Autoscaling group activity logs?

Comment: Yes I can see it scaling up to number of instances that I see and then as I mentioned in question it then scales down to good number for that also I see activity logs.
Btw I use binpack (memory) task placement strategy can that be the reason?